# How to handle clicking notifications?

Tags: android, notifications

I have this code for notifications which works but whenever I click on the notification the application force closes I don't know why.
I want when I click on the notifications for it to be cancelled, I also want to make it timed if it is possible, can you please help me?

Here is the code:

```
package egypt.interfaceAct;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Notifications extends Activity {

    NotificationManager nm;
    int uniqueID = 13393;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle programNum = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String body = programNum.getString("Activity");
        final String startTime = programNum.getString("Start");
        final String endTime = programNum.getString("End");
        nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.cancel(uniqueID);
        String notify = body + "Start at: " + startTime + " to: " + endTime;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,ProgramsList2.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 0);
        //String body = (String) ((TextView)parent.getChildAt(position)).getText();
        String title = "Egypt On The Go";
        //String time = body + "\n start at:" + startTime+ "\n end at:" + endTime.get(position);
        Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.egypt, notify, System.currentTimeMillis());
        n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, notify, pi);
        n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        nm.notify(uniqueID, n);
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        //Intent i = new Intent(this, ProgramsList2.class);
        //startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Here is the logCat maybe it will help:

```
06-25 19:06:19.818: E/AndroidRuntime(883): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{egypt.interfaceAct/egypt.interfaceAct.ProgramsList2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at egypt.interfaceAct.ProgramsList2.onCreate(ProgramsList2.java:68)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
06-25 19:06:19.824: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  ... 11 more
```

Here is the code for ProgramsList2

```
package egypt.interfaceAct;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import egypt.database.EgyptDataSource;
import egypt.database.Hotel;
import egypt.database.MySQLiteHelper;
import egypt.database.TA;
import egypt.database.TouringPrograms;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;


public class ProgramsList2 extends Activity{

    EgyptDataSource datasource;
    MySQLiteHelper sqlHelper;
    NotificationManager nm;
    static final int uniqueID = 13992;

    //ArrayAdapter<TouringPrograms> touringProgramAdapter;
    final String ACTIVITY_KEY = "activity";
    final String STIME_KEY = "Stime";
    final String ETIME_KEY = "Etime";
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> al;
    Map<String, String> map;
    SimpleAdapter sa;
    String[] from = {ACTIVITY_KEY, STIME_KEY, ETIME_KEY};
    int[] to = {R.id.tableTextID, R.id.tableText2ID, R.id.tableText3ID};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.programsmain);
        datasource = new EgyptDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.programsMainList);
        al = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

        nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.cancel(uniqueID);
        Bundle programNum = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String progNum = programNum.getString("ProgNum");
        final String dayNum = programNum.getString("DayNum");

        List<TouringPrograms> Activityvalues = datasource.getTouringPrograms(progNum, dayNum);
        final List<TouringPrograms> STimevalues = datasource.getTouringProgramsStartTime(progNum, dayNum);
        final List<TouringPrograms> ETimevalues = datasource.getTouringProgramsEndTime(progNum, dayNum);
        Object[] ActivityArray = Activityvalues.toArray();
        Object[] STimeArray = STimevalues.toArray();
        Object[] ETimeArray = ETimevalues.toArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < Activityvalues.size(); i++) {
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(ACTIVITY_KEY, ActivityArray[i].toString());
            map.put(STIME_KEY, STimeArray[i].toString());
            map.put(ETIME_KEY, ETimeArray[i].toString());
            al.add(map);
        }

        final List<TouringPrograms> Activityvalues2 = datasource.getTouringPrograms(progNum, dayNum);
        sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, al, R.layout.programstable, from, to);
        list.setAdapter(sa);
        //list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        //ListView lv = getApplication()

        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final String taName = Activityvalues2.get(position).toString();
                List<TA> HI = datasource.getTAHistoricalInfo(taName);
                if (HI.size()==0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                String historical = "Historical Info: " + TextUtils.join(", ", HI);
                List<TA> location = datasource.getTALocation(taName);
                String loc = "Location: " + TextUtils.join(", ", location);
                List<TA> tatype = datasource.getTAType(taName);
                String type = "Type: " + TextUtils.join(", ", tatype);
                List<TA> photo = datasource.getTAPhoto(taName);
                final String pho = photo.get(0).toString();
                List<TA> latitude = datasource.getTALat(taName);
                final String lat = latitude.get(0).toString();
                List<TA> longitude = datasource.getTALong(taName);
                final String lon = longitude.get(0).toString();
                final String startTime = STimevalues.get(position).toString();
                final String endTime = ETimevalues.get(position).toString();
                //Toast.makeText(hotelSearchList.this, "The hotel clicked is " + hotelName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProgramsList2.this);
                builder.setTitle("Information About " + taName);
                builder.setMessage(loc + "\n" + type + "\n" + historical + "\n");
                builder.setPositiveButton("View Photo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent i = new Intent(ProgramsList2.this, imageV.class);
                        i.putExtra("photo", pho);
                        i.putExtra("name", taName);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //dialog.dismiss();
                        Intent i = new Intent(ProgramsList2.this, Notifications.class);
                        i.putExtra("Activity", taName);
                        i.putExtra("Start", startTime);
                        i.putExtra("End", endTime);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNeutralButton("Map it", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent i = new Intent(ProgramsList2.this, mapActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("latitude", lat);
                        i.putExtra("longitude", lon);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.show();
                }
                return false;

            }});
        //list.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this);

    }

}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Can you post the source for ProgramsList2? Logcat suggests that's where the bug is.

Comment: Updated with the code for ProgramsList2

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the stack trace, it looks like this is the problematic code:

```
 Bundle programNum = getIntent().getExtras();
 final String progNum = programNum.getString("ProgNum");
```

You need to pass the required extra into the Intent you set on the notification.

Comment: Something like this

intent.putExtra( EXTRAS_KEY, extras );

Comment: I don't understand what you mean! What should I add to the previous code exactly?